# Ruby on Rails cannot acces db entries from backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am trying to use `Model.find id` when making calls from the backend and it will not work. If I create a new method in a model and make a route to it I can call wget to execute it. How can I use find with backend calls?

I get Couldn't find Model with 'id'=2

This is done for everything.

---

I didn't have Sidekiq configured correctly. Forgot to point it to the production environment.

Comment: Can you explain a little better? Are running this on the console? Where is the code for your model? What are the attributes that belong to it?

Comment: If you can't find a model with the Id of 2 it's because there is no model with the Id of 2 <3

Comment: This is running as a web app. And I can pull the model with the ID of 2 from a front end call and display it properly, but I cannot make any back end calls within this web app.

Comment: The web app is running with Rails environment of 'production'. When you say backend, do you mean `rails console`? You may need to run it as `RAILS_ENV=production rails console` to get the right environment.

Comment: Not console, no. I am talking about when I am using gems like sidekiq or resque, they give me the same error that it cannot find the ModelName.

Comment: Ugh never mind. I didn't have Sidekiq configured correctly. Forgot to point it to the production environment.